# Where is winapifamily.h in WDK

Tags: hid, wdk

I am trying to use an HID joystick in a project so I so I am trying to use WDK. The problem I am having is that hidsdi.h and ws2def.h both have #include  which I cannot find in the include folder. I have encountered this problem on both WDK 8.0 and WDK 8.1. I am using visual studio 2010. How do I get WDK up and running?

Comment: That header doesn't appear to be included in the WDK, or at least not 7600.16385.1. I find it on my machine in `\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared\`, which is the SDK installed by VS 2012. Not sure where VS 2010 might put it since Microsoft loves to shuffle that stuff with every release.

Answer (score 1):

`VS2010` compiler isn't compatible with `WDK`. `WDK8` is paired with `VS2012` and `WDK8.1` with `VS2013`. Earlier `WDK` versions aren't compatible with `VS` compiler and use their own.